# PostgreSQL ERROR: missing data for column

Tags: postgresql, csv

- UPDATE - this is the official data that the government it`s offering, and it`s really ugly. No UTF8, broken rows from what i see http://data.gov.ro/storage/f/2013-11-01T13:59:27.012Z/contracte-2007.csv

`CREATE TABLE` code

```
CREATE TABLE contracte (
  castigator text,
  castigatorcui text,
  castigatortara text,
  castigatorlocalitate text,
  castigatoradresa text,
  tip text,
  tipcontract text,
  tipprocedura text,
  autoritatecontractanta text,
  autoritatecontractantacui text,
  tipac text,
  tipactivitateac text,
  numaranuntatribuire text,
  dataanuntatribuire text,
  tipincheierecontract text,
  tipcriteriiatribuire text,
  culicitatieelectronica text,
  numaroferteprimite text,
  subcontractat text,
  numarcontract text,
  datacontract text,
  titlucontract text,
  valoare text,
  moneda text,
  valoareron text,
  valoareeur text,
  cpvcodeid text,
  cpvcode text,
  numaranuntparticipare text,
  dataanuntparticipare text,
  valoareestimataparticipare text,
  monedavaloareestimataparticipare text,
  fonduricomunitare text,
  tipfinantare text,
  tiplegislatieid text,
  fondeuropean text,
  contractperiodic text,
  depozitegarantii text,
  modalitatifinantare text
);
```

SQL Code

```
COPY contracte(Castigator,CastigatorCUI,CastigatorTara,CastigatorLocalitate,
   CastigatorAdresa,Tip,TipContract,TipProcedura,AutoritateContractanta,
   AutoritateContractantaCUI,TipAC,TipActivitateAC,NumarAnuntAtribuire,DataAnuntAtribuire,
   TipIncheiereContract,TipCriteriiAtribuire,CuLicitatieElectronica,NumarOfertePrimite,
   Subcontractat,NumarContract,DataContract,TitluContract,Valoare,Moneda,ValoareRON,
   ValoareEUR,CPVCodeID,CPVCode,NumarAnuntParticipare,DataAnuntParticipare,
   ValoareEstimataParticipare,MonedaValoareEstimataParticipare,FonduriComunitare,
   TipFinantare,TipLegislatieID,FondEuropean,ContractPeriodic,DepoziteGarantii,
   ModalitatiFinantare) 
FROM 'C:\\Sinaia\SEAP 2007-2015\contracte-2009.csv'
WITH DELIMITER '^'encoding 'WIN1252' NULL AS '/N';
```

Error that I get:

```
ERROR:  missing data for column "tip"
    CONTEXT:  COPY contracte, line 5312: "SC EUROSTRADE 
    SRL^7695851^Romania^Jilava^sediul social- Comuna Comana, Judetul Giurgiu"
    ********** Error **********

ERROR: missing data for column "tip"
SQL state: 22P04
Context: COPY contracte, line 5312: "SC EUROSTRADE SRL^7695851^Romania^Jilava^sediul social- Comuna Comana, Judetul Giurgiu"
```

If i try to add the CSV header then i get another error

```
ERROR:  extra data after last expected column
CONTEXT:  COPY contracte, line 5209: "S.C. ELECTRA LUC S.R.L.^12094467^Romania^Bucuresti^Bucuresti, str. Vasile Lascar nr. 165, sector 2^A..."
********** Error **********
```

Comment: if your file only has 5 columns then it would be better only declare these five columns in `copy`command?

Comment: all of the rows are important, and also when i was declaring less rows i was getting a error that there are more columns then said

Comment: Thanks for the edit, now it looks more beautiful.

Comment: can you give an example of the cvs file?

Comment: Ahh, now I see that I have forgotten to put the link, thanks for the heads up  http://data.gov.ro/storage/f/2013-11-01T13:59:27.012Z/contracte-2007.csv

Answer (score 0):

It's not a question of right or wrong command, the problem seems the data quality

when I run

```
\COPY contracte (Castigator,CastigatorCUI,CastigatorTara,CastigatorLocalitate,CastigatorAdresa,Tip,TipContract,TipProcedura,AutoritateContractanta,AutoritateContractantaCUI,TipAC,TipActivitateAC,NumarAnuntAtribuire,DataAnuntAtribuire,TipIncheiereContract,TipCriteriiAtribuire,CuLicitatieElectronica,NumarOfertePrimite,Subcontractat,NumarContract,DataContract,TitluContract,Valoare,Moneda,ValoareRON,ValoareEUR,CPVCodeID,CPVCode,NumarAnuntParticipare,DataAnuntParticipare,ValoareEstimataParticipare,MonedaValoareEstimataParticipare,FonduriComunitare,TipFinantare,TipLegislatieID,FondEuropean,ContractPeriodic,DepoziteGarantii,ModalitatiFinantare) 
FROM 'contracte-2007.csv' 
( format csv, header, delimiter '^', encoding 'win1252', null '/N' );
```

I get

```
ERROR:  missing data for column "subcontractat"
CONTEXT:  COPY contracte, line 8659: "INSTITUTUL NATIONAL CERCETARE DEZVOLTARE PTR.PROTECTIA MUNCII-INCDPM,,ALEXANDRU DARABONT"^1558391^Ro..."
```

As you can see, it's line 8659.

Comment: I managed to find a workaround in a complicated way, by first converting the file usign this php script

`<?php

$path_to_file = 'http://data.gov.ro/storage/f/2013-11-01T13:59:27.012Z/contracte-2007.csv';
$file_contents = file_get_contents($path_to_file);
$file_contents = str_replace("^", "|", $file_contents);
file_put_contents("contracte2007.normalized.csv", $file_contents);
`

Then i have to convert the file from ANSI to UTF8
And then loading the file directly in postgres via php script by using redbeanphp and MagicParser.php